# Вывод TV параметра одного ресурса

Tags: modx

Я только недавно перешел на MODX, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Натягиваю шапку сайта, телефон, адрес и другую инфу в шапке вывожу через TV параметры. Но как я понимаю, эти параметры привязываются к одному ресурсу (главная, внутренняя и др страницы) а мне необходимо чтобы эта инфа была на всех страницах. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить?

Возможно можно выводить TV параметры определенного ресурса?
В ассортименте есть migx, но он не совсем подходит для единичного поля, он для добавления полей подходит (как я понял).

В общем надеюсь на адекватную подсказку :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно шапку сайта закинуть в чанк. В шаблоне указать этот чанк и он будет един для всех страниц.

Если же требуется решать именно с помощью `tv-параметров`, то при наличии очень полезного компонента [pdoTools](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/) можно использовать вывод с помощью шаблонизатора *Fenom*.

Например, чтобы вывести в любом месте значение `tv-параметра` с именем `myTv`, из ресурса, `id` которого = 20, конструкция будет такой:

`[[#20.myTv]]`

---

В принципе этого должно хватить для решения задачи, но ещё, как вариант, можно создать сниппет, который будет вытаскивать `tv` из нужного ресурса:

```
$page = $modx->getObject('modResource', $id);
return $page->getTVValue('myTv');
```

Вызов соответственно примерно такой:

```
[[!getTv? &id=`20`]]
```