# MODX: А есть ли еще какие решения по генерации tv-параметров из других мест кроме ресурсов?

Tags: modx, pdotools

Как продолжение темы по вопросу: [Вывод TV параметра одного ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670665/)

Например, возможные значения тв параметра в виде таблицы/списка забивать в каком то месте, а в ресурсных страницах манагеры галочками выбирают, какие из этих значений нашего тв параметра выводить в публичную часть в виде, например селекта с множественным выбором и колличеством по каждому выбору.

Answer (score 1):

Можно подумать над решением/комбинации на базе [ClientConfig](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/clientconfig/index), [MIGX](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/migx), ну или [ContentBlocks](https://modmore.com/contentblocks/)